# ViewPager does not show anything?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I want to create Image slider with dots on the bottom of images.
My app shows well dots but not images.

CustomPagerAdapter.class

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private int[] mResources;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] resources) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mResources = resources;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlide);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, position+"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view)     {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
}
```

nonselecteditem_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
android:dither="true">
<size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>
<solid android:color="#d3d3d3"/>
</shape>
```

selecteditem_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
android:dither="true">
<size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>
<solid android:color="#7e7e7e"/>
</shape>
```

pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_screen"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:textColor="@color/bg_dark"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSlide" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

fragment_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_screen"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="activity_name">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space.normal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

activityFragment.class

```
public class activityFragment extends NetBaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener  
{

    int[] mResources = {
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp,
            R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp
    };

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
    private int dotsCount;
    private ImageView[] dots;


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void assignViews(View view) {
        super.assignViews(view);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);

        mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mResources);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        setPageViewIndicator();
    }

    private void setPageViewIndicator() {
        dotsCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {

            dots[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());

            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);

            final int presentPosition = i;
            dots[presentPosition].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(presentPosition);
                    return true;
                }

            });
            pager_indicator.addView(dots[i], params);
        }
        dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("###onPageSelected, pos ", String.valueOf(position));
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));
        }

        dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));

       if (position + 1 == dotsCount) {} 
       else {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateViews(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you even set a resource on your imageview.

Comment: what is NetBaseFragment class?

Comment: @Vryin i replaced " imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position])" by " imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sim_card_black_72dp) " in CustomPagerAdapter.class to set directly a ressorce to imageview, but no change. And mResources[position] in CustomPagerAdapter.class contains 6 ressouces that i have set in activityFragment.class

Comment: @Rucha Bhatt NetBaseFragment is a common class that i use in every child fragment.

Comment: I think the dots are being placed on top of the resource that you have set on your imageview. Thus, replacing the resource with the dot resource.